# longtabu + booktabs: mystery alignment tab in page-header converted to \cr

Tags: errors, booktabs, longtabu

Minimal testcase:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtabu}[c]{lrX}
\caption{Some table}
\bfseries Column 1 & \bfseries Column 2 & \bfseries Column 3%
\midrule
\endhead
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

Produces:

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> \endtemplate 

l.11 \end{longtabu}
```

Where in Hades is it getting an extra alignment tab from, and how do I fix it?  (Note that using `\textbf{}` instead of `\bfseries` in the header produces the same error, and so does having a `\\` between the header row and the `\midrule`.  It doesn't depend on the column format either -- I have tried `XXX` and `lrl` with the same results, and even tried inserting an extra column into the spec to gobble the alignment tab to no avail.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `\\` after the caption.

Comment: Well, that fixed *that* error, but now longtabu complains about a missing \noalign...want me to post another Q for that?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel you are also missing a `\\ ` before the `\midrule`

Comment: There we go -- got it working now